# Incorrect index.html load path on iOS application when published at AppStore

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Recently I've migrate my Cordova 2.9.x application to Cordova 3.6.0. 
On Android and Windows Phone, the application is working fine, and it was already published at Google Play Store and Windows Phone Store.

On iOS platform, the application is running fine when in development mode (running it on iOS simulators or devices) and I've also made an ad-hoc test with Testflight and everything works as expected.

The problem is, when published at App Store (after Apple's review), when user enters the application, it's trying to load the index.html located at **/www/production/index.html**, and the correct path is **/www/index.html**, and the user remains stuck at this error screen.

The old application version (using Cordova 2.9.x) used the **/www/production/index.html** path, but the new cordova project was started from scratch, and doesn't have any reference to this path.

I don't know what is happening. Has someone passed through a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the iOS config.xml because Cordova let's you customize it

myproject/platforms/ios/myproject/config.xml